# Background cover is not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem : the svg bar isnt responsive (see picture), anyone maybe has a solution for that? I seriously searched for around 1 1/2 hour now and im getting really frustrated :/

[image]

Here is my code :

**HTML** :

```
<div class="overview-footer">
  <img src="assets/layout/images/dashboard/progress_day.svg" 
       style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" />
  <img src="assets/layout/images/dashboard/progress_week.svg" 
       style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" />
  <img src="assets/layout/images/dashboard/progress_month.svg" 
       style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" />
  <div class="year"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.year {
background-image: url(assets/layout/images/dashboard/progress_year.svg);
width:100%;
height:20px;
display: table;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

}

thats the relevant svg data:

```
   <rect id="Rectangle-4" fill="#D8D8D8" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="20"></rect>
   <rect id="Rectangle-4" fill="green" x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="20"></rect>
```

EDIT:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ute15PscCtevJECeRLiE?p=preview 
 there you go

Comment: can you put your code on plunker?

Comment: sry, edited answere, could have done this instantly !

Comment: You don't need SVG to achieve what you want. What about simply nesting a div and giving it a percentage width based on the intended values (like 50% for year)?

Comment: i know..., my "crew" used a template with those bars included, so I tryed to get a solution with them. If there is no other way, I can still use the divs ! But yeah:) thx for comment anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is actually two-fold:

1. You are declaring explicit width and height on your SVG elements in the markup (e.g. `width="345" height="15"`). This forces preservation of aspect ratio.
2. You did not declare `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in your SVG elements, which  means that they will always scale proportionately.

The problem only arises when your `<div>` elements have a width of less than `345px`, which will cause the browser to scale the images the way you don't intend to.

If you remove these two attributes, your problem will go away: https://plnkr.co/edit/g26kjqYdtf8eNQtwI2Nb?p=preview

### Better solution: CSS + HTML-only solution

An alternative solution will be to simply use absolutely-positioned pseudo-elements to do the job. You are going to save a lot of time from maintaining these SVGs that only serve a single purpose, and their markup also appear absolutely bloated.

If you look at the code snippet below, a small modification to your markup and an overhaul of your CSS will mean that you no longer need to depend on SVGs:

```css
.overview {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.overviewDay::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80%;
}

.overviewWeek::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25%;
}

.overviewMonth::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 55%;
}

.overviewYear::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overview-footer">
  <div class="overview overviewDay"></div>
  <div class="overview overviewWeek"></div>
  <div class="overview overviewMonth"></div>
  <div class="overview overviewYear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: both solutions are working perfectly!, thx for the great help and the awesome explanation ! =)